# ion-content won't show when using Ionic core 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm developing an app that uses Vue.js and Ionic, but I can't figure it out why updating my Ionic core version breaks the ion-content tag, I tried googling if the tag was discontinued, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

To illustrate, I've made a example that uses Ionic core. With the latest Ionic version the ion-content tag doesn't show up, but if you switch to the older Ionic version, then it shows just fine.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ionic Test</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@0.0.2-30/dist/ionic.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <ion-app>
        <ion-page>
        <ion-header>
            <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>Example</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content class="content" padding>
            <ion-list>
                </ion-item>
                    <ion-label full>I'm an example text...</ion-label>
                    <ion-button>Example button</ion-button>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
        </ion-page>
    </ion-app>
</body>
```

Here's a jsFiddle for this code: https://jsfiddle.net/telmo/chk9h080/

Can someone explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: you have forgotten to open `ion-item` tag .. `<ion-item>`. A typo?

Comment: True, just fixed it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `@ionic/core` (aka Ionic4) version 0.0.4, there is no more `<ion-page>`. You directly put your header and content under the  `<ion-app>`.

If really necessary, you can wrap them in a `<div class="ion-page">`.

Comment: You guys are both right, removing the ion-page tag makes it so that the ion-content tag shows up again. Thanks!

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi: Suraj's fiddle got broken because now Ionic4 requires loading its CSS file as well. Here is a fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arhz6rss/41/

Answer (score -1):

Actually There is some height problem,so import css and write this code

......

**css**
.height{
height:100vh
}

It will solve your error

Comment: He mentioned his solution works with an older Ionic version, how's this a styling issue ?

Comment: Actually I have this problem in Ionic 5 So after adding style sheet it works