# How to show html in vue/ionic4

Tags: vue.js, ionic4

I'm trying the new Ionic_beta with Vue.
In a component I have a template showing some html.
If I put the the `<div>` containing the html in an `<ion-content>` directive the html is not shown. If I leave out the `<ion-content>` the html is shown, but now the panel with html is not scrollable.

html Show, not scrollable.....

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Over TRINL</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <div class="padding">
          <div v-html="legacySystemHTML"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

html NOT shown

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Over TRINL</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content>
            <div class="padding">
              <div v-html="legacySystemHTML"></div>
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `<ion-header>` and `<ion-content>` are not direct children of `<ion-app>` (e.g. to comply with Vue component requirement to have only 1 root element), you should wrap them in an element with `class="ion-page"`, therefore in your case:

```html
<template>
  <div class="ion-page"> <!-- apply the "ion-page" class -->
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Over TRINL</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <div class="padding">
        <div v-html="legacySystemHTML"></div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </div>
</template>
```

See also: [ion-content won't show when using Ionic core 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50265268/ion-content-wont-show-when-using-ionic-core-4/50265808#50265808)

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/ylz2jxIFjgUym98gyKeR?p=preview (without Vue)